# New kstream with Object

Tags: filter, cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

public KStream process(KStream input) {
need Employee is and Object inside Employer.How can I get that in return type.
And if I have to use ObjectMapper inside kstream to convert json to java and then pass, how can I do?
return input;
}

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

I want to create new Kstream
@input giving me Kstream

I need @Output json to be Kstream

Employeer have Employee Object and many other.I want to remove all unwanted data..